# How to create link_to into model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am wondering how I can handle this:

I want to generate a link_to into a body message when I save it through a model method.

Let say in this method, I create a new Message and wants to put a link inside it so when users of my website could click on it when going through every messages.

How would you do this in a nice way ? I tried this, but didn't work

Request.rb

```
  # Create a new Message after an acceptance
  def notify_acceptance
    msg = Message.new(subjects: [self.subject], author: self.evaluated_by)
    msg.body = "a warm welcome to #{ActionView::Helpers.url_to_user_profile(self.requested_by)} who just joined us!"
    msg.distribute([self.subject], self.evaluated_by)
    return msg.save!
  end
```

Here my Helper file :

```
module RequestsHelper
  def url_to_user_profile(user)
    link_to user.name, profiles_path(user.id)
  end
end
```

Thx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that you cannot. `link_to` is created from `ActionPack` where as models inherit from `ActiveRecord`.

A simple way around this is putting your `link_to` logic in your `helpers`.

For example:

app/views/index.html.erb

```
link_to_home
```

app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
def link_to_home
    if root_url?
        "Home"
    elsif params[:controller] = "posts" && params[:action] == 'index'
        "Home"
    else
        link_to "Home", root_url
    end
end
```

This way if you have pagination on the index page and that is your root url it will not link to Home. But if you used `link_to_unless_current` it will link to home even though it is the same controller and action that execute `link_to_unless_current`. Doesn't really matter if this example doesn't make sense. It's the rails way to keep `link_to` logic in helpers.

If it is really necessary you could just create a string in your model that has regular HTML and then escape that in the view.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    def link
        "<a href="#{url}">#{title}</a>"
    end
end
```

Then in your view you could have <%= @post.link %> and it would link to `url` and it would be called `title` assuming those were attributes on your `@post` object and you had something saved

Comment: Hum... There is no better practice than html string ?

Comment: Well it's bad practice to put `link_to` in the model. link_to is actually a very simple helper that you could build your self in any model. But most folks won't put it here because it doesn't follow MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this way?

`link_to user.name, :controller => "profiles", :action => "show", :id => user.id`

so:

`link_to "String you want", :controller => "controllers name", :action => "action", :(param name) => value`

and here you can insert how many params do you need

**EDIT**

with `profiles_url(user.id)` you get the url to this page, with that you can manualy create your linklike this:

```
msg.body =  "a warm welcome to <a href='#{profiles_url(self.requested_by.id)}'>#{profiles_url(self.requested_by.name)}</a> who just joined us!"
```

Comment: Does not work into model directly because link_to method is define in ActionView only.

Comment: yeah, i notice that now... but you can put that message to an view page, or you can call profiles_url and create your own links

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your model(maybe user) did not recognize profiles_path(user.id),
so add following in User model

```
include ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

I did not suggest include more view helpers in your model, you can't use link_to, but path helper method works, then create url like " link_name " in your msg
It works in Rails3.

Comment: however it broken mvc convention, so in my app, i create a PushMsg model and delegate all msg to this model, then other models will follow the mvc rule